# What is the name of the relation when I do generate_series

Tags: postgresql

When I do

```
select * from generate_series(1,5) s(a)
```

I guess the name of the relation is `s`.

But I was curious what the name of the relation is when I do

```
select * from generate_series(1,5)
```

or

```
select * from generate_series(1,5) a
```

Comment: @Jens A "relation" is the mathematically correct term here: it refers to an unordered-set-of-tuples: so a `TABLE`, `VIEW`, set-returning-`FUNCTION` are all examples of _relations_ as far as Relational Algebra (and SQL) is concerned - you've read _Codd et al_, right?

Comment: @Jens ...though I do get ever-so-slightly-annoyed when less-well-informed people use the term "relation" when they mean an _FK relationships_, \*le sigh\*

Comment: @Dai I used the term relation because I was not sure if it was a table or something else. As I see it, for example a table is a relation because the columns in a table are in relation with each other, otherwise they were not in the same table.

Comment: @ericj Yes, your usage of the term *relation* was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(At first I assumed the "table" that's returned was simply *anonymous*, just like [a `VALUES()` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html), but I was wrong; read on...)

Here's a DBFiddle I put together that shows the different ways of naming the table and/or column: https://dbfiddle.uk/Dm0fYj9e

---

```
/* Here, the resultset returned from `generate_series(1,3)` has the name `generate_series` with a single column also named `generate_series`: */
SELECT
  *
FROM
  generate_series(1,3);
```

| `generate_series` |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

---

```
/* When `AS q` is used like a table-alias `q` it actually renames both the returned table _and_ the column to the same name: */
SELECT
  abc123,
  abc123.*,
  abc123.abc123
FROM
  generate_series(1,3) AS abc123;
```

| `abc123` | `abc123` | `abc123` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

---

```
/* This shows the column being renamed without needing to give an alias to the function's resultset: */
SELECT
  generate_series AS columnNameGoesHere
FROM
  generate_series(1,3);
```

| `columnnamegoeshere` |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

---

```
/* This shows the column being renamed while also giving an alias to the function's resultset: */
SELECT
  generated_table_name.colName
FROM
  generate_series(1,3) AS generated_table_name( colName );
```

| `colname` |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

<sub>Note that while `columnNameGoesHere` and `colName` above were specified in the SQL, Postgres returns them as `columnnamegoeshere` and `colname` respectively (i.e. [it converts it to lowercase by default](https://Quoting%20an%20identifier%20also%20makes%20it%20case-sensitive,%20whereas%20unquoted%20names%20are%20always%20folded%20to%20lower%20case)).</sub>

Comment: Ah, thanks. So the name is generate_series. And the column also has that name. I did in your fiddle 'select generate_series.generate_series from generate_series(1,5). Then I saw it.